# Domain name change for OAuth 2.0 Client IDs leads to errors in google developers console

Tags: google-oauth, netlify, google-developers-console

I have a couple of different apps hosted on netlify using google APIs that have broken now because netlify changed their hosting to point to xxx.netlify.app instead of xxx.netlify.com

When I attempt to add the new domain to my oauth client IDs under "Credentials" I get an infinitely hanging wheel of death when I click "save"

I *thought* that wheel of death is caused by the new URL not being registered for the app, so I went to the settings for my application and tried to add the new domain, but it is failing as well.

I go to OAuth Consent Screen -> Edit App which then has another list of "authorized domain."

In the list, I see my old domain name:
foo.netlify.com

I try to add the new name:
foo.netlify.app

However, that auto-corrects to just plain netlify.app

I try saving that and get the following inscrutable error

> Error
>   The request failed because one of the field of the resource is 
>   invalid.
>
> Tracking Number: c4522674593257747

I don't see any way to read more about the error or to use the tracking number to find out more information.

Any troubleshooting pointers would be appreciated. I'd rather not start over from scratch, but at this point it looks like my best bet would be creating a whole new application and starting the whole credential/API Key process over for all of my apps that were hosted on netlify.

Comment: Got the exact same problem. And this one too: https://community.netlify.com/t/google-oauth-authorized-domains/13999

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and posted it in the google group. I have a reply from google cloud support which states that only top private domain is allowed as stated here [Setting Up OAuth2.0](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#authorized-domains)

> As the error clearly denotes and explained in this document, you can use any Top Private Domain as an Authorized Domain. So it seems to be the intended behavior.

I suppose that means only the domain owner can get a credential now.